# Filezilla default text editor

Tags: default

I am trying to set default text editor in FileZilla.

Installed applications on laptop are Visual Studio Code and Sublime Text.

Tried to set /usr/bin/code but it says that "file selected as default editor does not exist".

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem this way.

First, unistalled Sublime Text from AppCenter.

Installed using terminal, see official site https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html

While installing in terminal I saw line "ebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index..."

Now I opened /usr/share/applications/ directory, found sublime_text.desktop, opened this file and found in this file line "Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F"

Finally, used "/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text" for path for file editing editor in FileZilla and it is working.

Hope this will help someone.